# Error in getting user info by SPService

Tags: sharepoint

I am fetching user info by using spservice in Jquery and sharepoint.
In visual web part I have written in web part source.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="User DataUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserProfileService.User_Data.User_DataUserControl" %>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/AMAC/_layouts/UserProfileService/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js" ></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var curUserId;
           var curUserName;
           var curFullUserName;
           $().SPServices({
               operation: "GetUserInfo",
               async: false,
               userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
               completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                   $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function () {
                       curUserId = $(this).attr("ID");
                       curUserName = $(this).attr("Name");
                       curFullUserName = $(this).attr("ID") + ";#" + $(this).attr("Name");
                   });
               }
           });
       });          
</script>
```

But I am getting error:
as

'xData' is undefined

'jQuery' is undefined
Pls help me getting it corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load jQuery first because SPServices needs it: http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
> <script
> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Above spservices link 
User Information using SPServices